# Laravel read file from external hardisk

Tags: laravel, macos

i am doing a website that not intend to publish, only for personal use. i expect system to get file from external hardisk (because there are 19 GB of total file size, i don't want to use up my space on dropbox or internal hardisk).

FYI, I develop with Laravel on Mac for this project.

I have added custom driver in filesystems.php. I able to check existence of the file when the root is set to directory in my mac. It return true when the file is exists.

```
 'myApp' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => '/Users/CK/Samsung'
 ],
```

In myController.php

```
$exists = Storage::disk('myApp')->exists('file.txt');
echo $exists?"true":"false";
```

But i get logic exception "The root path /Volumes/SeagateExp is not readable" when the root is set to external hardisk (External hardisk works properly as i able to browse file with Finder and terminal)

```
'myApp' => [
                'driver' => 'local',
                'root' => '/Volumes/SeagateExp'
],
```

I was suspecting that permission not granted for external hardisk. But external hardisk SeagateExp already have permission to read. owner and user group also same with directory Samsung.

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 CK    staff     128 Sep  4  2020 Samsung
drwxrwxrwx   1 CK    staff  131072 Dec 31  1979 SeagateExp
```

I have search relevant information on web, but still cannot figure it out. Please help.

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel Framework 8.27.0

Comment: A website which accesses to 19GB external data?

Comment: @Raptor There are 1000++ video files inside, in total 19GB. If i keep them in local or cloud, it takes a lot of spaces. I don't often use those video files, so i  want to keep them inside external hardisk.

Comment: So, you mean your website is only accessible by yourself via your computer?

Comment: I think your website user and external drive user is not same, make them same or make permission on external to 777 and try

Comment: @Raptor Yup, it can only access by my computer and devices in same network. It's a project for family bonding activity =)

Comment: @SohagHasan Ya i suspect that too, but i don't really sure how to check the user of website. Owner(is it the user u mean?) of SeagateExp is CK, the directory Samsung which have same owner can be accessed by website too.

Comment: the local web server running Laravel can only access the files & folders at the document root. Your 19GB files are probably not inside the document root. Suggestion: move the Document Root along with the whole Lavarel to your external hard disk, and start the web server at your external hard disk. It's not related to permission at this moment.